# Test if property exists on a class at runtime

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

Something like this:

```
##class(MyApp.MyClass).%HasProperty("SomeProperty").
```

I looked into doing something like this:

```
set classDefinition = ##class(%Dictionary.CompiledClass).%OpenId(%class.Name)
```

and then looping through the Properties, however, I need to be able to use any class, not just `%class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple OO approach, you can use the following API:

```
Set tPropExists = ##class(%Dictionary.CompiledProperty).IDKEYExists("SomeClass","SomeProperty")
```

This should have much less runtime cost than loading the class definition data and looping over its properties (and thus loading the data for those properties as well).

If you still want to create a `%HasProperty()` helper method for your application classes, you can use the following base method (assuming you are on Cache 2010.2 or higher - I believe the `$this` special variable and the `$classname()` function were added in 2010.2, but that may have been in 2010.1.):

```
ClassMethod %HasProperty(pPropName As %String = "") As %Boolean
{
  Set tHasProp = 0
  If (pPropName '= "") {
    Set tHasProp = ##class(%Dictionary.CompiledProperty).IDKEYExists($classname($this),pPropName)
  }
  Quit tHasProp
}
```

Comment: I'm on 2009.1.2 and it doesn't appear that IDKEYExists() is available :(.  Still +1

Comment: Use %ExistsId(ClassName_"||"_Property) instead

Comment: @SSH - it should be noted that %ExistsId will throw an exception if the field is "", so best to wrap this call in a try catch.

Comment: @O.O I am fairly sure that `IDKEYExists()` is a generated method even that far back. A little-known feature is that some methods are automatically generated for an index defined on a class. I believe that an `<IndexName>Exists()` method is always generated for an index, even if the index is not unique. If the index is unique, then both `<IndexName>Open()` and `<IndexName>Delete()` should also be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to use a generator method (one of the really nice features in Cache objects) if run-time speed is important to you.

For example:

```
Method PropertyExists(Name) As %Boolean [ CodeMode = generator, ProcedureBlock = 1, ServerOnly = 1 ]
{
    Set %code=0
    S ClassDef=##class(%Dictionary.CompiledClass).%OpenId(%class)
    i '$IsObject(ClassDef)  $$$GENERATE(" Q 0")  Q $$$OK  
    I '$IsObject(ClassDef.Properties) $$$GENERATE(" Q 0")  Q $$$OK  
    S Key=""  F  S Key=ClassDef.Properties.Next(Key)  Q:Key=""  D
    . S CompiledProperty=ClassDef.Properties.GetAt(Key)
    . $$$GENERATE(" I Name="""_CompiledProperty.Name_""" Q 1" )
    $$$GENERATE(" Q 0")
    q $$$OK
}
```

Comment: I actually doubt that this code will be faster -- %ExistsId will just check one global node (very fast operation) which then will be cached in global cache, this one will have as much string comparision operations as number of your properties. So I'll recommend using %ExistsId.

Comment: I know there's caching, but everything isn't in the cache and it doesn't stay there forever.  But, yes, this could be slower.  It might be handy though for someone doing something similar where it makes more sense.